# Why is an internal static string is not accessible from outside the class?

Tags: c#, static, instance, internals, access-specifier

I have a class defined as follows:

```
class Foo
    {
        internal string IString;
        internal static string IstaticString;
        public Foo()
        {
            IstaticString = "static";
            IString = "non - static";
        }
    }
```

I am creating its instance in the main function as the following, in this case`IString` is accessible through the object, whereas `IstaticString` is not accessible. **Can anyone explain the reason for this?**

[image]

Comment: static members are not accessible from instances. `Foo.IstaticString ` should work

Comment: @ASh, That's the answer, can you add it as such?

Comment: http://www.davesquared.net/2008/07/why-cant-i-access-static-members-from.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static fields accessible from type not from instance. This `Foo.IstaticString` should work

Answer (score 2):

static members are not accessible from instances. `Foo.IstaticString` should work